# Multi Tenancy in ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern, multi-tenant

In the following example, what is an efficient way to implement multitenancy with minimal redundant code? In this scenario, tenant is a student. The students' school has 2 locations and each location is required to have the data (i.e, Courses) stored in a seperate database. When a student logs in, their location determines which database to pull from.

I'm using Entity Framework and Repository Pattern. Currently I have the implementation for accessing Location 1 DB. I've looked into different options to implement Location 2, such as injecting a TenantContext in the HomeController contructor, but I am stuck on how to set the correct database connection and what approach would be most efficient.

Below is the code for Location 1 only.

**Example Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ICourseRepository courseRepository;

    //How to set the correct repository to use based on location?
    public HomeController(ICourseRepository courseRepository)
    {
        this.courseRepository = courseRepository;
    }

    //Register for a new class
    public ViewResult Register()
    {
        var courseList = courseRepository.AvailableCourses();
        return View(courseList);
    }
}
```

**CourseRepository**

```
public class CourseRepository : ICourseRepository
{
    private Location1DB context = new Location1DB();

    public List<Course> AvailableCourses()
    {
        //Get available courses from Location 1 Course Table
    }
}
```

**Location1Model.Context.cs** *(This is genereated using EF DbContext Generator)*

```
public partial class Location1DB: DbContext
{
    public Location1DB()
        : base("name=Location1DB")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

**Web.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="Location1DB" ... />
     <add name="Location2DB" ... />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I don't think you understand what multi-tenant means.  Multi-tenant means where you have multiple web sites that all use the same code base, and are only differentiated by their URL (or possibly information in the users login).  This is the case where you might have two websites that offer similar content, and use the same code, but different themes or different layouts depending on which URL the user typed in.

Comment: Okay, so is there a term for this situation above? Where the code may overlap for different users but the data source is different.

Comment: This is an example of a post that lead me to multitenancy : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624154/using-multiple-databases-within-one-application

Comment: It depends.  Will a student only ever have one location?  What if they have classes in both locations?  If they're only ever at one location, then it could be considered multi-tenant because you're swapping the data in and out.  But, if you have to pull data from both databases then it changes things and it's just a multi-data source application.

Comment: A student will only have classes in one location. The student / course scenario was just something I created as an example for simplicity, but it may not be the best example. Regardless, yes the approach I'm looking for is how to handle multiple databases in one application, based on user's location. So ALL users in Location 1 will only see data from Location1DB.

Comment: how are you determining their location? could you determine that via a helper method and use your helper along side your DI container to create the correct instance of your db context? and what is the similarities between the databases? Are they just cloned copies? Could this problem be solved at the infrastructure level?

Comment: @HaveThunk The location ID is retrieved from a user's record (seperate data source) when the user logs in. The location is stored in the encrypted authentation cookie. The databases will not be _complete_ clones, but yes a lot of the tables within them will be the same (same name, same columns). They were seperated mainly so that they each database can be maintained without affecting another.

Comment: @HaveThunk Can you show me an example of how you are suggesting to set the DbContext?

Comment: sorry I'll try to post a proper answer when I get time tomorrow, but check this SO [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15353080/14515) and the castle windsor container doco [link](http://stw.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Inline-Dependencies&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

sorry I'll try to edit and provide a more complete answer when I get time tomorrow, but check this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15353080/14515) and the castle windsor container [doco](http://stw.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Inline-Dependencies&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) to get you started (also not sure what container you are using but all the major ones should have this functionality).

The thought would be to read the LocationID out of the cookie, grab the right connection string and have the container pass it as a parameter to your dbcontext.

DbContext is a partial class remember, so you could declare your own partial DbContext class, put an interface on it and pass that as a dependency into your repository.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links and your help. I am using StructureMap.